# How to Remove an Array from String object?

Tags: javascript, string

```
[{"id":"MGA - MMD","text":"MGA - MMD"},{"id":"MGA - WIE","text":"MGA - WIE"},{"id":"MGA - YP","text":"MGA - YP"}],MGA - MMD,MGA - WIE,MGA - YP
```

I want result like `MGA - MMD,MGA - WIE,MGA - YP`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the code what you tried

Comment: Please search on google or on SO! There are so many posts on this

Answer (score 0):

```
 var obj = [{"id":"MGA - MMD","text":"MGA - MMD"},{"id":"MGA - WIE","text":"MGA - WIE"},{"id":"MGA - YP","text":"MGA - YP"}];


  for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
   alert(" id:- "  + obj[i].id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get what you need. Just loop over the array and get the `id` value from each object of the array.

```js
var data = [{"id":"MGA - MMD","text":"MGA - MMD"},{"id":"MGA - WIE","text":"MGA - WIE"},{"id":"MGA - YP","text":"MGA - YP"}];

var res = data.map(obj => obj.id);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: If you use arrow syntax you don't need `return`, just `obj => obj.id`

Comment: Thanks for correcting @Barmar. Appreciate that.